# Java application access to azure keyvault : steps to generate auth token via client certificate

Tags: java, azure, client-certificates, azure-keyvault

I have referred following guides to setup AD certificate based application to connect to azure keyvault

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-use-from-web-application/

http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/authenticating-a-client-application-with-azure-key-vault/

http://kamranicus.com/blog/2016/02/24/azure-key-vault-config-encryption-azure/

We have a java application running on linux platform , we plan to call up azure keyvault rest api via certificate based authenticate.

Do we have any java based sample snippet to generate token via certificate stream ie certificate will be saved as string and passed on the fly to any token generation api. Examples in above links assume it to be installed in store

Answer (score 0):

@YogeshORai, According to your description & previous SO threads, I think the sample code in Java with Azure SDK from the [blog](http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/using-azure-key-vault-from-a-java-application/) is your want & the simple way for your current scenario, but not authenticate with certificate to get access token.